# How to use "awk" command to retrieve particular field, but the field number is given in runtime?

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

Im struggling to solve this.

./analyze.sh 9

### Inside Script:

```
lField=$1 (Command line argument)

cat "$(pwd)/results1/DSFTPTCPstats.6" | awk '{ print $lField }'
```

I want the values of the 9th field but it doesnt work. Tried different combinations in the 'print' section , cant solve... Would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell environment variable are not `awk` environment variables:

You can use the `-v` flag to turn one into the other:

```
pax> a=1;b=2;awk -vb=$b 'END{print a;print b}' </dev/null

2
```

In your particular case, this snippet may show it better:

```
pax> lField=2;echo "A B C" | awk '{print $lField}'
A B C

pax> lField=2;echo "A B C" | awk -vlField=$lField '{print $lField}'
B
```

In the first case, `$lField` is treated as `$0` so it prints the whole line. The second case has `lField` properly set to `2` so it only prints the second column `B`.

Comment: but need to give $b inside print.

Comment: awk -vb=$b 'END{print $a;print $b}'

Comment: @Kaushik, that was just example code to show how the variables could be transferred from shell to awk, using `$X` makes no sense since there's no records actually given to that script. The second code snippet is more relevant to your case.

Answer (score 0):

if you insist to do something like this

```
awk "{print "\$"${lField}}"
```